# How to mark-up source code with Structured Data (micro-data)

Tags: seo, schema.org, microdata, structured-data

I'm trying to use http://schema.org/Code to markup source code on a blog.  What is the correct way to markup source code?

I'm using the Google tool to test it: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Code" >
  some code
</div>
```

I thought something like that might work.  But nothing is registered.
I see that it inherits from creativeWork, so maybe I should be using one of those properties to contain the source code content instead, but I'm not sure. eg:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Code" >
  <meta itemprop="programmingLanguage" content="Java" />
  <span itemprop="exampleOfWork">import java.util.*;</span>
</div>
```

But the code is not registered. And it says "exampleofwork is not part of the schema" even though it should be inherited...

Does anybody know the correct/preferred approach?

Comment: Note that Google has published a new tool: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. Although it unfortunately thinks I want to see it in Japanese, just because I'm in Japan.  Even though the language selector in the footer says "English". :P  But that's Google's fault. not yours.   I'll use this from now on, thanks again!

Comment: You could try appending the parameter `?hl=en` (for English), i.e. https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [`text` property](http://schema.org/text) should be used for the actual code:

> The textual content of this CreativeWork.

A minimal example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Code">
  <pre>
    <code itemprop="text">
      import java.util.*;
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```